# Triggering scheduled reminders based on new Intercom customers

Tags: slack, reminders, intercom

I don't even know if SO is the right place for this question but I thought I'd give it a go as I've found answers on here before.

I'm trying to solve the following issue using widely available SaaS tools if possible as non devs will be using/managing this process.

We are trying to set up an internal scheduled reminder system for our team to make following up with our customers easier, Our work tool set is pretty standard:

Our CRM is Intercom,
Slack is used for internal chat
Notion for task management
Stripe for payments.

We would want it to go a little like this:

1.Customer signs up.

2.Intercom tags new customer.

3.Tag Triggers scheduled reminders (After 1, 3, 5, 7 days etc.) in Slack or Notion (preferably)/ or something else.

I've looked into Triggering reminders in Slack based on new messages in a channel as well as Using Zapier and IFTTT but haven't found a way thus far.

Any advice on tools/services that would help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achievable on zapier.

**It would look something like this**.

1. trigger (customer signs up), Intercom: New Company

   *optional*: add a filter where it will only continue if the new company has certain
   tags
2. action, "delay by zapier" **1 day**
3. do something, ie. post to slack/send email..
4. action, "delay by zapier" **2 days**
5. do something, ie. post to slack/send email..
6. action, "delay by zapier" **2 days**
7. do something, ie. post to slack/send email..
8. action, "delay by zapier" **2 days**
9. do something, ie. post to slack/send email..